# Java ActiveDirectory LDAP - Authenticate user with password hash

Tags: java, authentication, active-directory, ldap

I want to authenticate a active directory user with a on javascript client side hashed password. Is that possible? Currently I'm transfering the password in plain text to the server via a https connection.

This is my java side code to check the provided password:

```
public DirContext getDirContext( String dn, String password ) throws NamingException {
    Hashtable<String, String> ldapEnv = new Hashtable<>();
    ldapEnv.put( Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory" );
    ldapEnv.put( Context.PROVIDER_URL, this.providerUrl );
    ldapEnv.put( Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "simple" );
    ldapEnv.put( Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, dn );
    ldapEnv.put( Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, password );
    return new InitialDirContext( ldapEnv );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work, you need to close connection before returning `context`:

```
DirContext context = new InitialDirContext(ldapEnv);

if(context != null)
    context.close();

return context;
```

Comment: And with which algorithm have I to hash the password before I pass it to my method?